# Как реализовать прибавление значения AioGram?

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio, multiprocessing, threading

Есть телеграм бот написанный на Python и AioGram. Каждую секунду пользователю необходимо прибавлять некое число в базу данных.

Логика работы простая:

1. Бот забирает старое значение из БД.
2. Прибавляет к нему определенное число, например 1.
3. Записывает новое значение обратно в БД.

   Как можно реализовать такой функционал? Чтобы это работало для каждого пользователя бота, их может быть 1000+. Думаю использовать Threading или Multiprocessing, но может быть есть более лучшее решение?

Comment: Aiogram как раз для работы с многими пользователями, не нужно ничего дополнительно. Сохранять в БД число вместе с ID пользователя (он уникален). По нему же вытягивать старое значение и перезаписывать в БД.

Comment: @Дмитрий да, это понятно. Но можно какой-то пример кода как это реализовать, чтобы оно само работало, а не по нажатию кнопки и т.д. И не будет ли ситуации что бот занят только этим самым перезаписыванием, а пользователю отвечать с задержкой час?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA не совсем понял, у меня в бд хранится виртуальная валюта и ее нужно будет добавлять каждую секунду, или час например, как время в бд поможет мне ее прибавлять?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA хорошо, спасибо. Добавьте ответ, если хотите, я приму его

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать подход, который позволит избежать постоянного обновления баланса счета для многих пользователей.

Идея в том, чтоб храните последний баланс `balance` и дату `last_balance_calc_time` когда его считали. При чтении с БД вы всегда можете посчитать сколько времени прошло с `last_balance_calc_time`  и сколько с тех пор денег должно добавиться. Т.е. вы не храните деньги числом, а расчитывайте из значения `balance`, `last_balance_calc_time` и текущего времени. При приходе/расходе пересчитывайте текущий баланс и сохраняйте его вместе с текущим временем.

Дополнительно, можно пересчитывать баланс регулярно. Если делать это раз в секунду, то получится то, что вы хотите (учтите только, что с запуском может быть задержка, так что лучше смотрите на время прошедшее от прошлого пересчета). Можно запускать реже или вообще только при изменениях баланса.

Собственно регулярный запуск потока для пересчета делайте, как описано тут ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1418626/218971.

Имеет смысл одним запросом сразу всем пользователям добавлять деньги запросом типа такого:

```
update user_money
   set balance = balance + rate * (current_time() - last_balance_calc_time),
       last_balance_calc_time = current_time()
```